# Widget to get MAC Address as Input from user

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wanted to know if there's any Flutter widget which can take user input and validate and display it as device's MAC Address format.

I've tried to used TextFormField which takes "keyboardType" but couldn't find validator for verifying input to be MAC address and also displaying the text in "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [masked_text](https://pub.dev/packages/masked_text) widget which might help you.

For MAC address you can do something like this:

```
new MaskedTextField(
    maskedTextFieldController: _textController,
    mask: 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx',
    maxLength: 14,
    inputDecoration: new InputDecoration(
        hintText: "Enter your MAC address",
        labelText: "MAC",
    ),
),
```

Comment: Great widget. Thanks